# Two Definitions of Non-commutative $L^p$ space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Throughout, let $(\mathcal{M},\tau)$ be a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$, acting on a Hilbert space $H$, with normal semifinite faithful trace $\tau$.

In the survey article by [Pisier and Xu](http://dmitripavlov.org/scans/pisier-xu.pdf), the non-commutative $L^p$ space $1\leq p<\infty$ is defined as follows.  Let $S_+$ be the set of all positive elements $x\in \mathcal{M}$ whose support projection $\text{supp}(x)$ has finite trace. If $\mathcal{S}$ is the linear span of $S_+$, then the non-commutative $L^p$ space $L^p(\mathcal{M},\tau)$ is just the completion of $\mathcal{S}$ with respect to the norm 
$$|| x ||_p:=[\tau(|x|^{p})]^\frac{1}{p}.$$

On the other hand, for instance in [Nelson](http://magz.elibraries.eu/ul/3725/JFA%201974%20Volume%2015%20Issue%202.pdf), an approach analogous to the construction of the classical $L^p$ spaces in measure theory is used. Briefly, we introduce the concept of a $\tau$-measurable operator. These are, by definition, closed densely defined operators $x$ on $H$ affiliated with $\mathcal{M}$ and satisfy the condition 
$$\tau(E_\lambda(|x|)<\infty,$$
where $E_\lambda(|x|)$ is the spectral resolution of $|x|$ corresponding to the indicator function of $(\lambda,\infty)$.
By placing a specific topology on the set of all $\tau$-measurable operators, we obtain a metrizable topological $*$-algebra, denoted $L^0(\mathcal{M},\tau)$. 
After extending the trace $\tau$ to $L^0(\mathcal{M},\tau)$, we then define for $0<p<\infty$ 
$$L^p(\mathcal{M},\tau):=\{x\in L^0(\mathcal{M},\tau)|\ \tau(|x|^p)<\infty\}.$$

I have two questions:

1. Why are these two approaches in defining the non-commutative $L^p$ spaces ($1\leq p<\infty$) equivalent? Are there any references to proof(s) of this fact?
2. The space $\mathcal{S}$ above turns out to be weak$^*$ dense in $\mathcal{M}$. Will the completion of $(\mathcal{S},|| \cdot||_p$) still yield the non-commutative $L^p$ space if we assume that $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in a different operator topology?

Comment: Can't you just show that the map $\mathcal S\to L^0(\mathcal M, \tau)$ is an isometry for the p-norm, or am I missing something?

Comment: The two norms induced on S coincide by definition and S is dense in both spaces.  Finally, both ambient spaces are complete, which proves the desired statement.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks, I did not think carefully about this. I have to think harder!...:)

Comment: The link in the question no longer works, but it seems quite likely that the intended paper is 
Edward Nelson: Notes on non-commutative integration,
Journal of Functional Analysis
Volume 15, Issue 2, February 1974, Pages 103-116,
DOI: [10.1016/0022-1236(74)90014-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(74)90014-7)